# Access middleware in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

i am create a currency converter middleware in laravel based on subdomain wise, **app/Http/Middleware/Currency.php** this middleware is used to convert currency

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Currency
{
public function convert($request, Closure $next)
{
$sub=array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
$fromCurrency =  "AED";
$toCurrency = "$sub";
$amount = "1";
$url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=".$fromCurrency."+to+".$toCurrency;
$get = file_get_contents($url);
$data = preg_split('/\D\s(.*?)\s=\s/',$get);
$exhangeRate = (float) substr($data[1],0,7);
$convertedAmount = $amount*$exhangeRate;
$data = array( 'exhangeRate' => $exhangeRate, 'convertedAmount' =>$convertedAmount,       'fromCurrency' => strtoupper($fromCurrency), 'toCurrency' => strtoupper($toCurrency));
return json_encode( $data );
    }
}
```

and write in **Kernel.php** like

```
protected $middleware = [
     \App\Http\Middleware\Currency::class,
];
```

and show **Function name must be a string** error also in page,
how to access this return value in controller?

Comment: Why do want to use currency convert as middleware. It should be used as a helper

Comment: @Sehdev no need of middleware,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your purpose you should use Helper instead of Middleware. As per Laravel Documenation

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests
>   entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware
>   that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the
>   user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to
>   the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the
>   middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the
>   application.

You can create a custom Helper as below and use it anywhere in your app

**Step 1:** Create your a Currency Helpers class file and give it a matching namespace.  Write your class and method:

```
  <?php // Code within app\Helpers\Currency.php

    namespace App\Helpers;


class Currency
{
    public static function convert($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $sub=array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
        $fromCurrency =  "AED";
        $toCurrency = "$sub";
        $amount = "1";
        $url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=".$fromCurrency."+to+".$toCurrency;
        $get = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = preg_split('/\D\s(.*?)\s=\s/',$get);
        $exhangeRate = (float) substr($data[1],0,7);
        $convertedAmount = $amount*$exhangeRate;
        $data = array( 'exhangeRate' => $exhangeRate, 'convertedAmount' =>$convertedAmount,       'fromCurrency' => strtoupper($fromCurrency), 'toCurrency' => strtoupper($toCurrency));
        return json_encode( $data );
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create an alias:

```
<?php // Code within config/app.php

    'aliases' => [
     ...
        'Currency' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,
     ...
```

**Step 3:** Run `composer dump-autoload` in the project root

**Step 4:** Use it like this in your controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Currency;



 class SomeController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            Currency::convert($value);
        }
```

Comment: in your terminal run `composer dump-autoload` under your project

Comment: Non-static method App\Helpers\Currency::convert() should not be called statically show this type error why?

Comment: add `static` keyword after `public` like `public static function convert`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that middleware is the best way to implement the feature you want but to do what you asked using a middleware, the middleware itself must have a function called `handle` instead of `convert`. Also you could flash the result into your sessions to access it inside the controller.

Take note also the return of the handle function, as it is required for the process to continue

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Currency
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $explodedArr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $sub = array_shift($explodedArr);
        $fromCurrency =  "AED";
        $toCurrency = "$sub";
        $amount = "1";
        $url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=".$fromCurrency."+to+".$toCurrency;
        $get = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = preg_split('/\D\s(.*?)\s=\s/',$get);
        $exhangeRate = (float) substr($data[1],0,7);
        $convertedAmount = $amount*$exhangeRate;
        $data = array( 'exhangeRate' => $exhangeRate, 'convertedAmount' =>$convertedAmount,       'fromCurrency' => strtoupper($fromCurrency), 'toCurrency' => strtoupper($toCurrency));

        session()->flash('convert_result', json_encode($data) );
        return $next($request);
    }
}

// and you should be able to get the result in your controller like so
session('convert_result');
```